# Whmcs php execute in .tpl

Tags: whmcs

My whmcs theme css and js is very much. I did try combine css and js with a PHP script.

Php script need include a php file header. so in whmcs root don't have header.php

So I've created mycode.php  and theme folder inside mycode.tpl

Added following code on mycode.php and

`{php} echo 'hello world' {/php}` is worked

```
// instead of
require_once('vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

// use 
require_once('vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/SmartyBC.class.php');
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

But header.tpl is not working same code: `{php} echo 'hello world' {/php}`

I did create header.php and added smartbc code, still not working.

What can i do for this? Any idea?

Comment: Do you have enabled **Allow Smarty PHP Tags**  by General Settings

Comment: Yes it is enabled @ShivSingh.